# Flask app on Heroku - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, internal-server-error

I deployed my flask app on Heroku. I can display "index.html" which is the main page for the app. However, when the 'submit' button of the form is clicked, I get the 500 Internal Server Error.

My app works locally. There is no problem while the app is running in my local environment.

Heroku logs:

```
2020-05-28T16:34:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-28T16:34:22.121630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" request_id=86cc3f14-9304-42a4-b96b-c39e678a62d2 fwd="213.74.87.231" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=4291 protocol=https
2020-05-28T16:34:26.104211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/result" request_id=c6dd5146-83ca-4186-becc-bd48383c9dec fwd="213.74.87.231" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=847ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
```

My code looks like:

```py
    @app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def main_page():
        return render_template("index.html")


    @app.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def display_result():
        prediction_global = 0
        if request.method == "POST":
            # I didn't paste all code that is written in the actual code.

        return render_template("index.html", result=data)
```

And I have only one HTML page called "index.html".

Index.html:

```html
    <form action="/result" method="post">
        <select id=option-select>
            <option value="option1" name="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2" name="option2">option2</option>
         </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Predict" name="predict">
    </form>
    {% if result %}
         <h2> Result: {{ result }}$ per day. </h2>
    {% endif %}
```

I guess there is a problem with post routing because, in the logs, post method gives status=500

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you forgot to close your <select> tag

Comment: I didn't paste the complete HTML that's why closing <select> is missing. But, even so, thanks for ur answer

Comment: Have you tried to deploy this minimized version of your code and did it give the same error?

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail; in this case, start by running `heroku logs`. If you don't see any details there, add some logging statements to your `display_result()` function and try again.

Comment: Isn't that the code that's generating your HTTP 500?

Comment: I used TensorFlow in code, I guess the version of TensorFlow causes a problem.

Comment: "I guess the version of TensorFlow causes a problem"—it sounds like this _is_ a guess. On what are you basing this?

Comment: Dear @Chris, Thank you for your time and responses. I found the problem. I am using TensorFlow 2.2 on my local. However, TensorFlow 2.2 file size is 600mb which doesn't fit for deploying on Heroku. Thus, I used 2.1 for the TensorFlow version on Heroku. convert_to_tensor() function gave me an error in 2.1 version and I changed the convert_to_tensor(). And it worked! Thank you